# Why doesn't Kotlin let me use writeText extension?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have a Kotlin class with a method, which creates some text and then I want to write it to a file:

```
import java.io.File
import java.util.*
import kotlin.io.*

class MyClass {
    fun run() {
        val result = html {
            head {
                title { +"Entry page" }
            }
            body {
                h1 {
                    +"Map"
                }
                +"Some HTML code"
            }
        }
        File("target/wdef/index.html").writeText(result)
    }
}
```

I get an error - the `writeText(result)` is highlighted red and I get the error message `Error:(26, 40) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: writeText`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like a problem with build \ project configuration. Can you build it from CLI? Please answer here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem might be that you pass a wrong type to `writeText`. It requires `String`, but you pass an html building object `HTML`. Try to convert it with `toString`:

```
File("target/wdef/index.html").writeText(result.toString())
```

Comment: Thanks, but in `File("target/wdef/index.html").writeText(result.toString())` the `writeText` part is also highlighted red.

Comment: Are you sure the whole project is resolved? There should be more includes imo.